# How do I backup the data in SQL Server 2008 on a third party host?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, backup, sql-server-2008-express

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that is hosted by a third party host (heart internet).
How would I go about backing this up?

I used SQL Server Management Studio Express 2008 to create the tables within the database, but the backup options within this app seem to be only of use if you have direct access to the server machine (which I don't)

It's also worth noting that I am using change tracking - I presume this data would be lost should any backup be restored?

Thanks In Advance!

(PS - SQL Server 2008 novice here!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they allow you to run backups to a particular folder that you have access to you can just do it with the regular backup command:

```
backup database dbname to disk = 'y:\users\YourHomePath'
```

If they do not do that you might want to use the [Database Publishing Wizard](http://sqlhost.codeplex.com/) to script out your database (depending on the size this might be very slow)

Comment: Hmmm, came across the documentation on their site - looks like they only support using the database publishing wizard.
https://customer.heartinternet.co.uk/manage/support.cgi?action=view_question;question_id=714

I guess this is going to be very slow (around 1 million rows). Doesn't really seem like a very good backup procedure to me :( hopefully im wrong

Comment: Just noticed that the database publishing wizard does not work on SQL Server 2008...

Comment: Depending on what SQL tools/editions you have installed you might look for the following: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\DTSWizard.exe.  That MIGHT allow you to do some transfers at faster rates, but will be a lot harder to micro-manage at the end of the day.

Comment: And according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895179.aspx you can connect to SQL 2008...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .DAT file into a shared disk and to download it through FTP.